# mintMenu quits unexpectedly each time I open a file

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, mate-panel

I am in Linux Mint with Mate desktop. Each time I open a file (text file, image file, libreOffice, mp3...) I receive the following error:

[image]

The problem does not occur if I open filebrowser windows.
If I reload the mintMenu, it always quits again, as soon as I open a new document.

It started when I was under Mint 20.3, after I gave a `mate-panel --reset` command.

Here is a list of things that I have tried:

- I have "Reset all panels" from the menu I get right-clicking the panel: the problem is still there;
- I have upgraded the system to Mint 21.1: the problem is still there;
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled (in synaptic) several packages (`mate-panel`, `libmate-panel-applet-4-1`, `mintmenu`, and many more that I thought related to the issue): same problem;
- I have created a new user, and switched user: the problem is not present in the new user account (!!);
- following [this suggestion](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=677025#p677025) I have renamed the folders `/home/fabio/.config/mate`, `/home/fabio/.config/mate-session`, `/home/fabio/.config/mintmenu`, `/home/fabio/.config/menus` and then logout -> login: the system re-creates the folders, but the problem is still there.

Here is what I read in the `syslog` at the time the problem occurs:

```
Feb  4 20:52:58 Fabio-EliteBook systemd[1388]: Started app-flatpak-org.kde.kate-11545.scope.
Feb  4 20:52:58 Fabio-EliteBook kernel: [ 4161.234665] mintmenu[11520]: segfault at 4 ip 00007fec36a772ea sp 00007ffe16735e70 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2404.29[7fec3694a000+383000]
Feb  4 20:52:58 Fabio-EliteBook kernel: [ 4161.234677] Code: 5c 41 5d 41 5e c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 fd 48 8b 7f 08 48 85 ff 74 05 e8 2a 7f 12 00 48 8b 7d 18 <8b> 47 04 83 e8 01 89 47 04 85 c0 7f 05 e8 e4 9e 07 00 48 8b 7d 20
Feb  4 20:52:58 Fabio-EliteBook systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 11562/UID 0).
Feb  4 20:52:59 Fabio-EliteBook systemd-coredump[11563]: Process 11520 (mintmenu) of user 1000 dumped core.#012#012Found module linux-vdso.so.1 with build-id: 5184a2f16f7dde2a79239f62e4c110f6f1068d69#012Found module librsvg-2.so.2 with build-id: d90852732e03f74b9e1b885131f22beb1791061c#012Found module libpixbufloader-svg.so with build-id: 255490aaa9d197965f278b8508e82447d76e8a4a#012Found module libmate-menu.so.2 with build-id: bbb7bdf311ff6bfbb826128244ef7762213df40c#012Found module libibus-1.0.so.5 with build-id: e3dae4899cdd44fe8f7e77ab5ba21e1fa4859782#012Found module im-ibus.so with build-id: 76823247c5f509589ca3b1bbf2bc8eb38c26b029#012Found module libssl.so.3 with build-id: e2cc2e6cff81fe9dc26f9d03e9865a0d1964ed95#012Found module _ssl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so with build-id: bded0cfcd752c74abc263c6ae97cc4fd45738a76#012Found module libcrypto.so.3 with build-id: 0c369eae63403647fb36564ae61733900d651702#012Found module _hashlib.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so with build-id: 4ef58614fa4f471fe6e6b8e17bfadcace6225b9b#012Found module _lzma.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so with build-id: af722e2d9bb669a93f2223c2a3f244c492da8309#012Found module libbz2.so.1.0 with build-id: e56b62c27bcc7ace8f9be36b255bd7b31bfde405#012Found module _bz2.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so with build-id: 79ea0fc57c71ba2d556ba5b2e90e721071dc4700#012Found module libdconfsettings.so with build-id: 28be9445dc37a4f123f206cda2ffc7dea558a315#012Found module libmate-panel-applet-4.so.1 with build-id: 4bf8e73ff52547f70500f116a177d3757effafc4#012Found module setproctitle.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so with build-id: ee1fa48c5d14af7c962b3c3aad50860d71bc8d4e#012Found module libgvfscommon.so with build-id: e7fa580fb91bb21aac9fc69229e0961dc743f2b1#012Found module libgvfsdbus.so with build-id: 28abe694dac468552cc1d23d6f643e7989de85e8#012Found module libgcc_s.so.1 with build-id: 09c4935b79388431a1248f6a98e00d7dc81b8513#012Found module libstdc++.so.6 with build-id: f57e02bfadacc0c923c82457d5e18e1830b5faea#012Found module libicudata.so.70 with build-id: b1c2496dd0543023c7a19c961bb7f3abc818f465#012Found module libicuuc.so.70 with build-id: bef3ff1d70aadd68aab07d858a759360c8b919ae#012Found module libxkbfile.so.1 with build-id: b585f533dd10bd8c043f887705d4e45828baf206#012Found module libxml2.so.2 with build-id: 2025ebcf5a6f422d82bdf345647c746def8ecaa2#012Found module libxklavier.so.16 with build-id: a581072418d786fb4a1d160ee7143bbd977025e7#012Found module libgnomekbd.so.8 with build-id: 636c4ae86d1bff2aa2cb92b39b42e41ff714ec7c#012Found module libgnomekbdui.so.8 with build-id: e01ea8bdf45e3995a2449f1cb4bd8e6bd886efa5#012Found module libxapp.so.1 with build-id: c2604faecc8b0da20c901263b5c716224cd5818e#012Found module libxapp-gtk3-module.so with build-id: a879184917c79399c48158e5c6f139cd89499ab4#012Found module libgpg-error.so.0 with build-id: 3fbec71c67bee60d8aef00697ee187079b0fb307#012Found module libgcrypt.so.20 with build-id: 60a5e524de0ed8323edf33e9eb9127a9eee02359#012Found module libcap.so.2 with build-id: 9e11e3bca4b0a25d047cb36e933e1d727663cf8e#012Found module liblz4.so.1 with build-id: a85971851cd059f1af80d553c8e7170d42ec59a1#012Found module libzstd.so.1 with build-id: 5d9d0d946a3154a748e87e17af9d14764519237b#012Found module liblzma.so.5 with build-id: b85da6c48eb60a646615392559483b93617ef265#012Found module libsystemd.so.0 with build-id: 61fb1ea64197576f79977fb27e1be39a088e7f3e#012Found module libatspi.so.0 with build-id: 2843c68233d5ba81da3d6bc31422e49472873dba#012Found module libdbus-1.so.3 with build-id: 63e8b99215502138cb63afd6d65851a5e837ed49#012Found module libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 with build-id: 7e8009077fbdcd7bf094c51bf78742b96f216d73#012Found module libatk-1.0.so.0 with build-id: b93088667fbd06f6b72d273403d352e7c0554698#012Found module libgtk-3.so.0 with build-id: 9a340345f5e200f42140f3cb4bacb407e91843f8#012Found module libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 with build-id: a7dd79c7ea8ec4d5791f83f9a8f34ffbfa8c3801#012Found module libepoxy.so.0 with build-id: 5ea53a2b100e4b044eee19d5222881a724abf046#012Found module libwayland-client.so.0 with build-id: a85980f4efa33fa5cadfbf257349fef99d499427#012Found module libwayland-egl.so.1 with build-id: e13dfac5961e8fb58c54984fe8110a73c2f5ef99#012Found module libwayland-cursor.so.0 with build-id: abcd1ab467757354ac36fd0938b82d47d7aebe1f#012Found module libxkbcommon.so.0 with build-id: a4b17d939092101dc8f6b2a1d70eaf1fddb2dd51#012Found module libXfixes.so.3 with build-id: a9c550a40b8154a3b4b5e2ac182bb50c013c3f18#012Found module libXdamage.so.1 with build-id: 8358b7625700dc247fa21fb4304cba877a28bb04#012Found module libXcomposite.so.1 with build-id: 2c84db5342304ba1a76db7dd9b7a3bfaa8a716ce#012Found module libXcursor.so.1 with build-id: d936a5db46d8babb0f2cc490df36b6b18a16d8aa#012Found module libXrandr.so.2 with build-id: 069f930a2b41f3908a1a92b1a51c38bd13a559e2#012Found module libXi.so.6 with build-id: 8ff5a3ac871a90fd9d0a7917c61f748a41c6b5ee#012Found module libXinerama.so.1 with build-id: 9823bebfa26a681265db4aeb09abf44deec38401#012Found module libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 with build-id: cb231e62ccba07e561d1d08804e975f615a6faf6#012Found module libgdk-3.so.0 with build-id: 97b768ef80858a79741be2492754d948989e63c6#012Found module libjpeg.so.8 with build-id: c54abff9294357e28532a76a049a4cb2542fc15b#012Found module libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 with build-id: 374b383e3b68b5d8b552519094129f401596e502#012Found module libgraphite2.so.3 with build-id: 5ffbc76fc948f6b88d766a7210c2e6a329a6c278#012Found module libdatrie.so.1 with build-id: 128b6874a47f2b783d9e9060d3caaee4110bfd3d#012Found module libharfbuzz.so.0 with build-id: 3b9c495c079286b8d1f55d0937a0a771593eb7e6#012Found module libthai.so.0 with build-id: afa54530349e68380815d606d15dbfda8952799f#012Found module libfribidi.so.0 with build-id: 6e075a666e1da8ffdb948d734e75d82b1b6dc0fb#012Found module libpango-1.0.so.0 with build-id: 2d778a30dd59c0673b0208c538999ccc0991093a#012Found module _cairo.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so with build-id: a4873ac2dc5e5d07917a2aca5b92914128feecbb#012Found module libmd.so.0 with build-id: cd2d2f71b3967ebde30e2aa43b8eb63339020c06#012Found module libbsd.so.0 with build-id: 9a6c72469251e2feb63e175ef5cb944ce6e00df3#012Found module libbrotlicommon.so.1 with build-id: 43a72967cf84155914c8b3e915926733d1e57c11#012Found module libXdmcp.so.6 with build-id: 6b60f99504aa1d3999ea02a14366d1a39d6c5dcf#012Found module libXau.so.6 with build-id: 7089b383cacbfc1760634a3be19a923e51fe3315#012Found module libbrotlidec.so.1 with build-id: 4b1f390dd6e24d49684db8b2443d082379e8e977#012Found module libuuid.so.1 with build-id: 64c0d0cb22fa2bdeca075a0c0418ba5ff314b220#012Found module libXext.so.6 with build-id: 9fb1880e02dfa11a8c39cd1a170109de08302059#012Found module libX11.so.6 with build-id: b8d9314a7185312e4813abcac67d8b68ae2fd690#012Found module libXrender.so.1 with build-id: 7ccbfa4c24e93c42fa50dd2e42fa277630f9650c#012Found module libxcb-render.so.0 with build-id: cb521131fd3b0f2ee6056cbc2014b3b8ef0d5c0e#012Found module libxcb.so.1 with build-id: 1bef862a339557aa16c34c7a4b27f8f3aea90517#012Found module libxcb-shm.so.0 with build-id: edb24ef4079aa423edcc50a3bb0dfb912fe8a57a#012Found module libpng16.so.16 with build-id: d58bf7c11ac793d528926238d831792b5ef792cf#012Found module libfreetype.so.6 with build-id: e3aff1d56fb1aecc723a73882f7d0f208a36c4bc#012Found module libfontconfig.so.1 with build-id: 0bb435fdd5ec37178e14ea03bb36f779a4b72a94#012Found module libpixman-1.so.0 with build-id: 5e936cdac032b6048d9d1a8c0bb0e4a10c86d48c#012Found module libcairo-gobject.so.2 with build-id: 71b5bd37d77ea1862d2ed00e9f6ead482f307db8#012Found module libcairo.so.2 with build-id: 60a39c3684e41370bd0a59ed1ecbdccf47e30069#012Found module _gi_cairo.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so with build-id: a1854770e645829fbda3b0d466420ee9035a66be#012Found module libpcre2-8.so.0 with build-id: 184a841c55fb7fe5e3873fcda8368c71016cd54c#012Found module libblkid.so.1 with build-id: cdf95a964e3302bb356fefc4b801fae8c4340b31#012Found module libselinux.so.1 with build-id: 6fa53202ce676297de24873c886443b2759bfd8a#012Found module libmount.so.1 with build-id: eeb33f2b4b9c3
Feb  4 20:52:59 Fabio-EliteBook systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@28-11562-0.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb  4 20:55:01 Fabio-EliteBook CRON[11598]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

and this is what happens when I hit "Reload" on the error dialog window:

```
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook dbus-daemon[9169]: [session uid=1000 pid=9169] Activating service name='org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory' requested by ':1.19' (uid=1000 pid=9470 comm="mate-panel " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook dbus-daemon[9169]: [session uid=1000 pid=9169] Successfully activated service 'org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory'
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11621]: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintMenu/mintMenu.py:498: DeprecationWarning: MatePanelApplet.Applet.set_background_widget is deprecated
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11621]:   self.applet.set_background_widget(self.applet)
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11621]: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintMenu/mintMenu.py:176: DeprecationWarning: Gtk.Alignment.new is deprecated
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11621]:   Align1 = Gtk.Alignment.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11621]: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintMenu/mintMenu.py:177: DeprecationWarning: Gtk.Alignment.set_padding is deprecated
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11621]:   Align1.set_padding(10, 5, 10, 0)
Feb  4 20:59:16 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11634]: #015Reading package lists... 0%#015#015Reading package lists... 100%#015#015Reading package lists... Done
Feb  4 20:59:17 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11634]: #015Building dependency tree... 0%#015#015Building dependency tree... 0%#015#015Building dependency tree... 50%#015#015Building dependency tree... 50%#015#015Building dependency tree... Done
Feb  4 20:59:17 Fabio-EliteBook org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[11634]: #015Reading state information... 0% #015#015Reading state information... 0%#015#015Reading state information... Done
```

I am relatively new to Linux, I have the feeling that it is all about a messed up configuration file (because of the fact that in the new user account the problem is not present), but I am not sure which config to remove.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `mintmenu --reset` change anything? This should clean up some settings in your dconf database (`~/.config/dconf/user`) and remove `~/.linuxmint/mintMenu`, see [github.com/linuxmint/mintmenu/blob/master/usr/bin/mintmenu](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintmenu/blob/master/usr/bin/mintmenu). Btw., your segfault looks like [this one](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintmenu/issues/255#issue-665116744) which is still an open issue.

Comment: Just tried `mintmenu --reset`, no change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem!
I don't know why it worked, but here is what I did.

1. After receiving the error, instead of hitting "Reload", I closed the error dialog
2. I then right-clicked in the panel (in the place missing the mintmenu), and added a new mintmenu
3. I rebooted the system
4. At the reboot I found TWO mint menus, one next to the other (!!)
5. I tried to open a document, and I got no error! the problem was solved!
6. I don't know if this step is really needed, but instead of removing the redundant second mintmenu right away, I first moved it in another location of the panel. Actually, beyond some of the "system applets" on the right (keyboard layout, battery, etc)
7. Then I removed the redundant second mintmenu.

After few reboots and some other usual activities, the problem seems solved. I also have no errors or warnings in the syslog.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem lies in the configuration files, you might try using `sudo apt-get purge <package>` in a terminal to uninstall instead. According to the `apt-get` man page, use of `purge` will delete any configuration files along with the package.